# How are nodes laid within the DOM tree?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am learning JavaScript.
I am new to the topic of Document Object Model (DOM).

I am confused about how are nodes laid within the DOM tree?

I used this HTML file.

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="page">
<h1 id="header">List</h1>
<h2>Buy groceries</h2>

<ul>
<li id="one"><em>emText</em>directText</li>
</ul>

</div>

<div id='TDiv'>
<h1 id='travelhead'>headText</h1>
</div>

<script src="javac.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I used this JavaScript file.

```
var li = document.getElementById('one');

var emText = li.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue;
var directText = li.firstChild.nextSibling.nodeValue;

document.write(emText + '<br />');
document.write(directText + '<br />');

var div = document.getElementById('TDiv');
var headText = div.firstChild.nextSibling.firstChild.nodeValue;
document.write(headText);
```

The two variables:

`var li = document.getElementById('one');`
`var div = document.getElementById('TDiv');`

hold the location of the `li` element node and `div` element node within the DOM tree.

**Although this line gives the right answer but it is formulated unexpectedly:**

```
var headText = div.firstChild.nextSibling.firstChild.nodeValue;
```

It is used to get the text value of the text node within the `H1` node element within the `DIV` node element. So I expected it to be written like this:

```
var headText = div.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue;
```

`DIV` has `H1` as a first child, and in turn `H1` has a first child of Text node.

`div.firstChild` should returns `H1`.
`div.firstChild.firstChild` should returns the Text node of `H1`.
`div.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue` should returns the value of the Text node.

How are those nodes really laid within the DOM tree?!

Comment: It should be noted that the mechanics of DOM building from HTML have nothing at all to do with JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is whitespace between the `<div>` and the `<h1>` - the newline. That will (or might) be turned into a text node.

If you changed the HTML:

```
<div id='TDiv'><h1 id='travelhead'>headText</h1></div>
```

then the DOM would not have that extra text node.

This is a good illustration of why it's a terrible idea for JavaScript code to expect a particular structure from an HTML document.